# How to make a text have a <a ref> tag in business layer in ASP

Tags: asp.net

I want a text in my datatable to have a link to a another page.  And I do this by the means of the business layer.

here is my code:

DataTable reportTable = new DataTable();

```
        DataColumn colLeaveType = new DataColumn("leaveType", typeof(System.String));
        DataColumn colNoDays = new DataColumn("No. of Days", typeof(System.Int32));
        DataColumn colStartDate = new DataColumn("Start Date", typeof(System.String));
        DataColumn colEndDate = new DataColumn("End Date", typeof(System.String));
        DataColumn colConvert = new DataColumn("Convert To Leave", typeof(System.String));


        reportTable.Columns.Add(colLeaveType);
        reportTable.Columns.Add(colNoDays);
        reportTable.Columns.Add(colStartDate);
        reportTable.Columns.Add(colEndDate);
        reportTable.Columns.Add(colConvert);

        reportTable.AcceptChanges();

        foreach (DataRow row in tempTable.Rows) {
            DataRow newRow = reportTable.NewRow();
            reportTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

            newRow[colLeaveType] = row["LeaveType"].ToString();
            newRow[colNoDays] = row["DaysCredit"].ToString();
            newRow[colStartDate] = row["StartDate"].ToString();
            newRow[colEndDate] = row["EndDate"].ToString();
            newRow[colConvert] = "Convert"; // this is something like this <a href="newPage"> Convert </a>

            reportTable.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

How to do this? Is this possible?

Thanks

RJUY

Answer (score 0):

```
newRow[colConvert] = "<a href='newPage'>" + row["Convert"].ToString() + "<a/>";
```

Of course you really need to test the values from your database for null before you cast them.  And using a StringBuilder to generate the link would also be best.

Comment: It didn't work.  I shows the text literally "<a href='www.yahoo.com'>Convert</a>".. why is that so? here is the code newRow[colConvert] = "<a href='www.yahoo.com'>Convert</a>";